# Azure Cosmos with Next JS - MongoServerSelectionError: Command hello not supported prior to authentication ERROR

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, connection-string, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

While connecting Azure Cosmos for MongoDB from Next JS - mongodb (version: 5.0.1) I am getting this error -

```
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getSessionAndUser] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getsessionanduser Command hello not supported prior to authentication. {
  message: 'Command hello not supported prior to authentication.',
  stack: 'MongoServerSelectionError: Command hello not supported prior to authentication.\n' +
    '    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\\Users\\siddh\\Projects\\RareGoods\\blockchain-certificates-admin\\node_modules\\mongodb\\lib\\sdam\\topology.js:284:38)\n' +     
    '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)\n' +
    '    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)',
  name: 'MongoServerSelectionError'
}
```

Mongo helper code is -

```
import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } from 'mongodb';

const uri = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTHDB_URI;
const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 };

let client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
let global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
```

I tried changing library version to 4.x.x, but nothing worked. The error is same for each combination.